# JDBC connection lost while UNLOADing from Redshift to S3. What should happen?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Reshift newbie here - greetings!
I am trying to unload data to S3 from Redshift, using a java program running locally which issues an UNLOAD statement over a JDBC connection. At some point the JDBC connection appears lost on my end (exception caught).
However, looking at the S3 location, it seems that the unload runs to completion. It is true however that I am unloading a rather small set of data.
So my question is, in principle, how is unload supposed to behave in case of a lost connection (say, a firewall kills it or even someone does a kill -9 on the process that executes the unload)? Will it run to completion? Will it stop as soon as it senses that the connection is lost? I have been unable to find the answer neither by rtfm'ing, nor by googling...
Thank you!

Comment: Not an answer, but I read in one SO question that for large unloads it's possible to see the data coming into S3 batch by batch.  If so, if the query were killed midway, it would imply that yes, you could end up with a partially completed unload +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UNLOAD` will run until it completes, is cancelled, or encounters an error. Loss of the issuing connection is not interpreted as a cancel.

The statement can be cancelled on a separate connection using [`CANCEL`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CANCEL.html) or [`PG_CANCEL_BACKEND`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_CANCEL_BACKEND.html).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CANCEL.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_CANCEL_BACKEND.html

Comment: Thank you, Joe. If I could ask for one last thing - could you please point me to where I could find that piece of information in the docs? Thanks!

Comment: I had the commands as hyperlinks but I guess it wasn't obvious. So I added the links to the answer text as well. 

Comment: I noticed the two links, the one thing that I haven't yet understood is: is this behavior generally applicable to all redshift queries (they don't 'stop' upon loss of jdbc connection only upon CANCEL) or is it just an UNLOAD thing?

Comment: No, queries will _usually_ cancel on loss of connection. `COPY` and `UNLOAD` are slightly different because they run at a lower level in the cluster.